# Vuejs cannot push to nested array

Tags: vue.js

First question on stack overflow, I apologize if I am asking in the wrong place. New to Vue and been trying for several days to finish a small project. I've simplified it but here it is. I want to be able to enter as many customer names as I need, and then be able to add as many customer's childrens names as I need. So an array of customers with a nested array of children. I can get the customers to add, but I cannot figure out why I cannot push a new element into the children's array. Here is my code.

```
new Vue ({
el: '#app',
data: function () {
    return {
            formdata: [],
            fields: [{
                name: '',
                childs: [{
                    cname: '',
                }]
            }],
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addRow: function() {
            this.fields.push({
                name: "",
                childs: [{
                    cname:'',
                }],
            });
        },
        addChild: function() {
            this.child.push({
            });
        },
    },
});
```

And my html

```
<div id="app">
  <button class="btn btn-success" @click="addRow">Add</button>
    <div v-for="field in fields" >
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" v-model="field.name">
      </div>
      <div v-for="child in field.childs" >
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Child" class="form-control" v-model="child.cname">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success" @click="addChild">Add</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Again, the problem is that i can push a new "name" to the fields array, but i cannot push a new child into the fields child array. I have been trying every permutation of child childs field fields etc, trying to find how to reference that array. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `addChild` method, you need to be accessing the `childs` property of the relevant `field`. Currently, you are trying to access the `childs` property of the Vue instance, which doesn't exist.

You should pass the relevant field to the `addChild` method like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" @click="addChild(field)">Add</button>
```

And then update your `addChild` method to reference the `childs` array of the `field` passed in:

```
addChild: function(field) {
  field.childs.push({});
}
```